# Galois group over extension field of quotient ring based on cyclotomic polynomial

Tags: ring-theory, galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $\Phi_m(X)$ be the $m$-th cyclotomic polynomial, $p$ be a prime, and $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]/\Phi_m(X)$ be a quotient ring.

I believe that $\mathcal{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)\mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$ but, I do not know how it works, where $\zeta$ is the primitive $m$-th root of unity ($\zeta \in Z_p$ and p > m).

What happens when applying the galois group permutation on an element over $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]/\Phi_m(X)$.

For example, if $m$=8 and $p$=17. Then the quotient ring is $\mathbb{Z}_{17}[X]/(X^4+1)$ and an element over the ring is $a=a_0 + a_1 X + a_2 X^2 + a_3 X^3 \in \mathbb{Z}_{17}[X]/(X^4+1)$, $a_i\in \mathbb{Z}_{17}$.

So, What is the corresponding operations of $\mathcal{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q})$ and what's happening after applying that?

Comment: "For example if $m$=8. Then the polynomial ring is $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]/(X^4+1)$ and an element over the ring is $a=a_0 + a_1 X + a_2 X^2 + a_3 X^3 \in \mathbb{Z}_p[X]/(X^4+1)$" ... This is false: first of all, $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]/(X^4+1)$ is *not* a polynomial ring but just merely a quotient ring. Second, what is that $\;p\;$ there for you? Third: what all this has to do with cyclotomic extensions **of the rationals**? I think you're mixing many  things here...

Comment: For what it's worth, $x^4+1$ splits over the integers modulo 17.

Comment: $x^4+1$ is split into 4 linear term. How can I calculate each factor ?

Comment: $x^4+1$ splits into 4 linear factors modulo $p$ if and only if $p\equiv1\pmod8$. But, what DonAntonio said, factorization of $x^4+1$ doesn't really show in $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)\Bbb{Q})$. It does show in the splitting of primes (or prime ideals), but you didn't tag this [tag:algebraic-number-theory]